# Can I implement Index/IndexMut for a type that has locked data?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I've got a struct that contains some locked data. The real world is complex, but here's a minimal example (or as minimal as I can make it):

```
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct LockedVector<T> {
    stuff: Mutex<Vec<T>>,
}

impl<T> LockedVector<T> {
    pub fn new(v: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        LockedVector {
            stuff: Mutex::new(v),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Index<usize> for LockedVector<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl<T> IndexMut<usize> for LockedVector<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
        let thing = self.stuff.get_mut().unwrap();
        &mut thing[index]
    }
}

impl<T: Display> Display for LockedVector<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let strings: Vec<String> = self
            .stuff
            .lock()
            .unwrap()
            .iter()
            .map(|s| format!("{}", s))
            .collect();
        write!(f, "{}", strings.join(", "))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_stuff = LockedVector::new(vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
    println!("initially: {}", my_stuff);
    my_stuff[2] = 5;
    println!("then: {}", my_stuff);
    let a_mut_var: &mut usize = &mut my_stuff[3];
    *a_mut_var = 54;
    println!("Still working: {}", my_stuff);
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is implement the `Index` and `IndexMut` traits on a struct, where the data being indexed is behind a Mutex lock. My very fuzzy reasoning for why this should be possible is that the result of locking a mutex is sort-of like a reference, and it seems like you could map a reference onto another reference, or somehow make a sort of reference that wraps the entire lock but only de-references the specific index.

My much less fuzzy reasoning is that the code above compiles and runs (note the `todo!`) - I'm able to get back mutable references, and I assume I haven't somehow snuck past the mutex in an unthread-safe way. (I made an attempt to test the threaded behavior, but ran into other issues trying to get a mutable reference into another thread at all.)

The weird issue is, I can't do the same for `Index` - there is no `get_immut()` I can use, and I haven't found another approach. I can get a mutable reference out of Mutex, but not an immutable one (and of course, I can't get the mutable one if I only have an immutable reference to begin with)

My expectation is that indexing would acquire a lock, and the returned reference (in both mutable and immutable cases) would maintain the lock for their lifetimes. As a bonus, it would be nice if `RwLock`-ed things could only grab/hold the read lock for the immutable cases, and the write lock for mutable ones.

For context as to why I'd do this: I have a `Grid` trait that is used by a bunch of different code, but backed by different implementations, some of which are thread-safe. I was hoping to put the `Index` and `IndexMut` traits on it for the nice syntax. Threads don't generally have mutable references to the thread-safe Grids at all, so the `IndexMut` trait would see little use there, but I could see it being valuable during setup or for the non-thread-safe cases. The immutable `Index` behavior seems like it would be useful everywhere.

Bonus question: I absolutely hate that `Display` code, how can I make it less hideous?

Comment: For the `Display` question: `#[derive(Debug)]` instead of implementing `Display`, then use `Debug` formatting later: `println!("initially: {:?}", my_stuff);`

Comment: @PitaJ I should have been clearer - I want the customize-ability and pretty-ness of Display, (not just here but in general) but find that implementing it for anything with collections inside is ugly. Is there a more elegant way to do the actual display implementation?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't implement `Display` unless that structure is meant to be shown directly to an end-user (which does not apply to any generic collection like yours). `Debug` for anything else - you can manually implement it if you want. You can use things like [`debug_list`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.debug_list)

Comment: One plus of using `Debug` is that it can be pretty-printed with the alternate format string `{:#?}`

Comment: @PitaJ So I realize I'm drifting off topic here, but it's often not generic collections I want this for - I can have something that holds a vector of some concrete type, and the implementation looks just as ugly.

Comment: I'd recommend opening a separate question with a more concrete example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.get_mut) you'll see it's only possible precisely because a mutable reference ensures that there is no other reference or a lock to it, unfortunately for you that means that a `get_ref` for `Mutex` would only be possible by taking a mutable reference, that's just an artificially limited `get_mut` though.

Unfortunately for you since `Index` only gives you a shared reference you can't safely get a shared reference to it's contents, so you can't implement an `Index` so that it indexes into something behind a `Mutex`.

Comment: Okay. I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no, but does the math change if I restrict `T` to `T : Copy`? I ask because it seems like in the actual use case (i.e., `myStuff[2]`), the reference returned is immediately de-referenced, so it seems like returning a value rather than a reference is almost something that works.

Comment: Yea you guessed it, `Index` requires a reference, no matter if it's immediately dereferenced. There is nothing preventing you from implementing your own `get` which is a common workaround for index's limitations though which can have any signature you like.

Comment: Yeah, I already have a `get` that does exactly that, but I got all excited at being able to make my code look pretty. Oh well.